# Scoped type variables require explicit foralls. Why?

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-systems, quantifiers, type-extension

If you want to use GHC's [lexically scoped type variables](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables), you also have to use [explicit universal quantification](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#explicit-foralls). That is, you have to add `forall` declarations to your functions' type signatures:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall a . [a] -> [a]      -- The `forall` is required here ...
f (x:xs) = xs ++ [x :: a]       -- ... to relate this `a` to the ones above.
```

Does this actually have anything to do with quantification, or did the extension writers just coopt the `forall` keyword as a convenient marker for where the new, wider scoping applies?

In other words, why can't we leave out the `forall` as usual? Wouldn't it be clear that type variables in annotations within the function body refer to variables of the same name in the function signature? Or would the typing be somehow problematic or ambiguous?

Comment: I submitted my own answer below, but I wonder whether there are additional subtleties I haven't considered. ...

Comment: Since Haskell-98 doesn't have scoped it's a compromise to only have the scoped variables introduced by forall.  That way old code still works when turning on ScopedTypeVariables.  (Arguably, Haskell should always have had scoped type variables.)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the quantifier is meaningful and is required for the types to make sense.

First note that there's really no such thing as an "unquantified" type signature in Haskell. Signatures without a `forall` are really implicitly quantified.  This code ...

```
f :: [a] -> [a]                         -- No `forall` here ...
f (x:xs) = xs ++ [x :: a]               -- ... or here.
```

... really means this:

```
f :: forall a . [a] -> [a]              -- With a `forall` here ...
f (x:xs) = xs ++ [x :: forall a . a]    -- ... and another one here.
```

So let's figure out what this says. The important thing is to notice that the type variables named `a` in the signatures for `f` and for `x` are bound by *separate* quantifiers. This means that they are *different* variables, despite sharing a name. So the above code is equivalent to this:

```
f :: forall a . [a] -> [a]
f (x:xs) = xs ++ [x :: forall b . b]    -- I've changed `a` to `b`
```

With the names differentiated, it's now clear not only that the type variables in the signatures for `f` and `x` are unrelated, but that the signature for `x` claims that `x` can have *any* type. But this is impossible, since `x` must have the particular type bound to `a` when `f` is applied to an argument. And indeed the type-checker rejects this code.

On the other hand, with a single `forall` in the signature for `f` ...

```
f :: forall a . [a] -> [a]              -- A `forall` here ...
f (x:xs) = xs ++ [x :: a]               -- ... but not here.
```

... the `a` in the signature on `x` is bound by the quantifier at the beginning of `f`'s type signature, so this `a` represents the same type as the type represented by the variables called `a` in `f`'s signature.

Comment: Apparently according to https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.2/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#scoped-type-variables it's possible to do this kind of scoping in expressions and in pattern type signatures as well. but I don't quite understand pattern type signatures.

Comment: What happens if you enable ScopedTypeVariables but don't enable ExplicitForAll? Then you can't write `forall`. Then what is the effect of ScopedTypeVariables? In a snippet that I wrote, ScopedTypeVariables allowed one to declare that a particular value was of `Char` type inside a function body. Without ScopedTypeVariables, it did not allow me to write it. Which is strange since I'm not trying to unify any type variables.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, `-XScopedTypeVariables` is basically useless without `-XExplicitForAll`. Half the time I forget to set the latter and end up tearing my hair out for five minutes before I realize that's the problem.