# How do I specify a type variable used in an inline type, is the same as a type variable used in a function definition?

Tags: haskell, type-inference, type-variables

(Apologies if my terminology is wrong).

I'm trying to write a wrapper function that handles exceptions: if the given `IO` action throws, it returns `Nothing` (inside an `IO` context of course), but if the given `IO` action succeeds, it returns `Just v`.

```
tryMaybe :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
tryMaybe action = do
    result <- (try action) :: IO (Either SomeException a)
    return $ case result of
        Left _  -> Nothing
        Right v -> Just v
```

This results in the compiler error message:

```
  Couldn't match type `a' with `a1'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for tryMaybe :: IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
          at src/Database.hs:33:13
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           an expression type signature: IO (Either SomeException a1)
           at src/Database.hs:35:15
    Expected type: IO a1
      Actual type: IO a
    In the first argument of `try', namely `action'
```

I'm guessing that the type variable `a` in the first line isn't the same as the `a` in the third line - they just happen to have the same name in the source code, and the compiler has renamed it `a1` in the error message.

So how do I tell Haskell that these are the same types?

Comment: Have you tried `ScopedTypeVariables`?

Comment: Related explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15800878/scoped-type-variables-require-explicit-foralls-why

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to enable the [`ScopedTypeVariables`](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Scoped_type_variables) extension, and the change the type signature of the top-level function to start with `forall a .`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

...

tryMaybe :: forall a . IO a -> IO (Maybe a)
...
```

The `forall` syntax brings the type variable `a` into scope for the entire body of `tryMaybe`, rather than it being limited to the type signature which is the default. This is mainly a historical anomaly rather than a deliberate design.

Comment: Aha yes that sorted it. I understand that GHC is trying to maintain backwards compatibility with Haskell 98 here, but I would have thought a warning about type variable shadowing (if that's the right term), plus a hint to investigate that language extension, might be helpful to newbies like me. Ah well I live and learn. Many thanks!

Comment: @stusmith I think a shadow warning is a great idea.  You should file a ghc enhancement ticket.