# Haskell: Type Error Trying when using generics

Tags: haskell

I am a Haskell beginner, and when I compile the Haskell source code, when trying to make a function to implement an lazy at least as long as

```hs
module Main where

import Data.Maybe

main = undefined

foldWhilel :: (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
foldWhilel f acc xs = go acc xs
  where
    go :: (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
    go acc [] = Just acc
    go acc (x:xs) = if isNothing new_acc then Just acc else go (fromJust new_acc) xs
      where
        new_acc :: Maybe b
        new_acc = f x acc
```

with this error pesky stupid nonsense error, considering (at least for what I know) that this should perfectly work. Because the function go and the function parameter are well designed in the type annotations

```
dist-newstyle/gh.hs:15:19: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘b2’ with ‘b’
      ‘b2’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          new_acc :: forall b2. Maybe b2
        at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:14:9-26
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foldWhilel :: forall a b.
                        (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
        at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:7:1-56
      Expected type: Maybe b2
        Actual type: Maybe b
    • In the expression: f x acc
      In an equation for ‘new_acc’: new_acc = f x acc
      In an equation for ‘go’:
          go acc (x : xs)
            = if isNothing new_acc then Just acc else go (fromJust new_acc) xs
            where
                new_acc :: Maybe b
                new_acc = f x acc
    • Relevant bindings include
        new_acc :: Maybe b2 (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:15:9)
        f :: a -> b -> Maybe b (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:8:12)
        foldWhilel :: (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
          (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:8:1)
   |
15 |         new_acc = f x acc
   |                   ^^^^^^^

dist-newstyle/gh.hs:15:21: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘a1’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          go :: forall b1 a1. b1 -> [a1] -> Maybe b1
        at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:10:5-29
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foldWhilel :: forall a b.
                        (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
        at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:7:1-56
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘x’
      In the expression: f x acc
      In an equation for ‘new_acc’: new_acc = f x acc
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a1] (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:12:15)
        x :: a1 (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:12:13)
        go :: b1 -> [a1] -> Maybe b1 (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:11:5)
        f :: a -> b -> Maybe b (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:8:12)
        foldWhilel :: (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
          (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:8:1)
   |
15 |         new_acc = f x acc
   |                     ^

dist-newstyle/gh.hs:15:23: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘b1’
      ‘b1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          go :: forall b1 a1. b1 -> [a1] -> Maybe b1
        at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:10:5-29
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          foldWhilel :: forall a b.
                        (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
        at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:7:1-56
    • In the second argument of ‘f’, namely ‘acc’
      In the expression: f x acc
      In an equation for ‘new_acc’: new_acc = f x acc
    • Relevant bindings include
        acc :: b1 (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:12:8)
        go :: b1 -> [a1] -> Maybe b1 (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:11:5)
        f :: a -> b -> Maybe b (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:8:12)
        foldWhilel :: (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
          (bound at dist-newstyle/gh.hs:8:1)
   |
15 |         new_acc = f x acc
   |
```

Comment: You need to enable (and then use) [`ScopedTypeVariables`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395881/how-do-i-specify-a-type-variable-used-in-an-inline-type-is-the-same-as-a-type-v)

Comment: 'Generics' in Haskell refers to datatype generic programming. Languages like Java use generics for what Haskell calls (parametric) polymorphism.

Comment: Minor note: using `isNothing` and `fromJust` is a common beginner anti-pattern. In many languages, one needs a boolean to perform a conditional like `if myBoolean then .. else ..`, so it's easy to be tempted to use `isNothing`. However, that loses information, reducing the type `Maybe a` to `Bool` and the values `Nothing / Just x` to `True / False` -- note how `x` was lost! Then, `fromJust` can crash the program if we call it by mistake on `Nothing`. You don't have to risk crashes if you use pattern matching: `case myMaybeVal of Nothing -> ... ; Just x -> ... use x` is 100% safe.

Comment: @chi I think that Haskell should no have any if keyword, because Haskell elementary operation is pattern matching.

Comment: @chi Where I can find material about Haskell patterns and anti-patterns.

Comment: @Delfin I wish there were a resource for that! I don't know what to suggest. You could read about [boolean blindness](https://sboosali.github.io/mirror/boolean-blindness.html) and have a look at [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters). Yes, `if` is a bit redundant in Haskell, and is only a shorthand for `case expression of True -> thenCase ; False -> elseCase`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to fix the error is to remove type signatures for `go` and `new_acc`.

You cannot use type signatures this way because say `b` used in the signature of `foldWhilel` and `b` used in the signature of `new_acc` are two completely different variables that just happen to have similar names. On top of that, `(a -> b -> Maybe b)` in`go` signature is wrong regardless (`go` has no such parameter, is is using `f` from an outer scope).

If you want to use `b` throughout you function with the same meaning, you need to enable and apply [Scoped type variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395881/how-do-i-specify-a-type-variable-used-in-an-inline-type-is-the-same-as-a-type-v):

```
{-# Language ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Maybe

foldWhilel :: forall a b. (a -> b -> Maybe b) -> b -> [a] -> Maybe b
foldWhilel f acc xs = go acc xs
  where
    go :: b -> [a] -> Maybe b
    go acc [] = Just acc
    go acc (x:xs) = if isNothing new_acc then Just acc else go (fromJust new_acc) xs
      where
        new_acc :: Maybe b
        new_acc = f x acc
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/11WEjonPM)

Comment: Imho scoped type variables should be on by default. Every other language I can think of that has generics has them in-scope during the function body. It's just so much more intuitive.

Comment: It is also the only(?) extension where ghc won't suggest enabling it, so if you are not aware of it you have to figure it out by asking on SO

Comment: is the keyword forall by default or  has to be enabled by the extension?

Comment: @Iceland_jack Indeed. We get a warning when we shadow a variable, we should also get one when we shadow a type variable, suggesting to either rename it or to turn on scoped type variables. (Or just make scoped variables the default)

Comment: @Delfin `forall` is a non-standard keyword enabled by this extension (and some others). You need to use it in order to make a variable scoped.